# Huawei Mobile Services SDK not compliant with Google Play Policies?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-play

I have a problem with google play console .

You can check error in attached pic:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UptFJ.jpg)

but I have not used Huawei Mobile Services SKD .
Why was my application rejected?

its my dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.9",
"@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
"@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^8.3.0",
"@react-native-community/slider": "4.1.12",
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.3.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.3.0",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
"@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
"axios": "^0.22.0",
"firebase": "^9.6.5",
"formik": "^2.2.9",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-native": "^0.66.2",
"react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
"react-native-animated-pagination-dots": "^0.1.72",
"react-native-animated-splash-screen": "^2.0.5",
"react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
"react-native-countdown-timer-hooks": "^1.0.3",
"react-native-drop-shadow": "^0.0.2",
"react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.4",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
"react-native-navigation-bar-color": "^2.0.1",
"react-native-progress-wheel": "^1.0.5",
"react-native-pull-to-refresh": "^2.1.3",
"react-native-pure-jwt": "^2.2.2",
"react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
"react-native-restart": "^0.0.22",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-screens": "^3.7.2",
"react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0",
"react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.0.0",
"react-native-spinkit": "^1.5.1",
"react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
"react-native-system-setting": "^1.7.6",
"react-native-toast-notifications": "^3.2.2",
"react-native-track-player": "2.1.2",
"react-native-webview": "^11.15.0",
"react-query": "^3.25.0",
"react-timer-hook": "^3.0.5",
"realm": "^10.20.0-beta.5",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
"rn-tooltip": "^3.0.1",
"yup": "^0.32.9"}
```